# Implementation of a map function

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to implement a Scheme-like `map` function, i.e.

```
map([X1, X2, ..], Fun) ->[Fun(X1), Fun(X2), ...]
```

I wrote this code:

```
map([], Fun, []).
map([H|T], Fun, [HO|TO]) :- call(Fun, H, HO), map(T,F,TO).
```

Now, looking at this run:

```
?- map([1,2,3], plus(1), X).
X = [2, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 4] ;
ERROR: map/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (9) map([3], _G380, _G351) ?
```

1. How can I make it stop after the first solution provided?
2. How can I trace it?If i use `trace` it stop the execution after the first solution.

Comment: `SWI-Prolog version 5.10.4 for i386`

Comment: Note that SWI-Prolog has a `maplist` predicate that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) the code you posted has a problem: `map(T,F,T0)` should be `map(T,Fun,T0)`. without this change i get the error you mentioned immediately; with this correction it runs flawlessly. (it is also a good idea to change `map([], Fun, [])` to `map([],_Fun,[])` since you dont use the variable `Fun` - you should get a warning for singleton variables)

2) when you trace it and reach the first solution, press `;`. alternatively, in swi-prolog, press the `spacebar` instead of `enter` and the tracing will continue.

```
6 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 6 ?- X = 1 ; X = 2.
   Call: (7) _G522=1 ? creep
   Exit: (7) 1=1 ? creep
X = 1 ;
   Call: (7) _G522=2 ? creep
   Exit: (7) 2=2 ? creep
X = 2.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed `F` n `Fun`. It does not give me that error anymore, but it still gives me more than one solution (always the same, the correct one, but repeated). I really cannot understand why.

Comment: can you try this: add to the code `foo(_,42).` and then run `map([1,2,3],foo,X).` and `map([1],foo,X)` it's quite weird, i'm running 5.10.4 too. are you on linux? in any case you can fix it with a wrapper predicate: `map_w(X,Y,Z):- once(map(X,Y,Z)).`

Comment: Yep, I'm on Linux. Thank you for your help.